# Reading a CSV file into another CSV not saving

Tags: python, csv, goose

So my CSV_Output file is empty, although I don't get any errors. I'm trying to simply add one more column from my CSV_to_Read file. The print of article.cleaned_text works. So I feel like I'm just doing something stupid here. Thanks!

```
from csv import reader, writer
import unicodecsv as csv
from goose import Goose

with open('CSV_to_Read.csv','r') as csvfile:
    readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile, encoding='utf-8')
    out = writer(open("CSV_Output.csv", "a"))
    for row in readCSV:
        g = Goose({'browser_user_agent': 'Mozilla', 'parser_class':'soup'})
        try:
            article = g.extract(url=row[0])
            print article.cleaned_text
            out.writerow([row[0], row[1], row[2], row[3], row[4], row[5], row[6], article.cleaned_text, row[7], row[8], row[9]])
        except Exception:
            pass
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you open a file object to your output file, but do not close it.

> `out = writer(open("CSV_Output.csv", "a"))`

It's possible that the data is buffered and hasn't been flushed to the disk. One way to avoid this error is to make sure you close file objects. The latter is handled for you by the file object context manager (i.e. the `with open(path) as file:` syntax).

Thus, i recommend changing your code to:

```
with open('CSV_to_Read.csv','r') as csvfile:
    readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile, encoding='utf-8')
    with open("CSV_Output.csv", "a") as outfile:
        out = writer(outfile)
        for row in readCSV:
            g = Goose({'browser_user_agent': 'Mozilla', 'parser_class':'soup'})
            try:
                article = g.extract(url=row[0])
                print article.cleaned_text
                out.writerow([row[0], row[1], row[2], row[3], row[4], row[5], row[6], article.cleaned_text, row[7], row[8], row[9]])
            except Exception:
                pass
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Hmm it appears that the problem still persists.

Comment: Hmmm sorry about that, I was able to reproduce the file not flushing to disk without closing on my machine. My next idea is to ask you remove the `except Exception` and see if there are any problems that got ignored. This can be over-aggressive in catching exceptions in some cases.